# Right word to describe "people working together"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Please consider the below sentence:

> Dean Shrivastava and his **__** of twenty faculty members took care of the classes.

Which word of the below fits best into the above blank?

> a. Gang
>   b. Team
>   c. Crew
>   d. Work Party

To me, all seem to suit fine. However, I cannot figure out which fits best.

Dictionary meanings:

> Gang: an organized group of workmen
>   Team: a cooperative unit
>   Crew: an organized group of workmen
>   Work party: an organized group of workmen

These definitions I got from http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/.

Comment: Not "gang", it has negative connotations. If it were me, I'd go with "team", unless you mean to imply that Dean Shrivastava is the leader, then "crew" is better.

Comment: Presumably you have looked in a dictionary and found some impartial definitions. Do they really not help? If they don't, it would be good to include the definitions in your question along with why they are not useful.

Comment: Do the 20 other people constitute the faculty, or a subset? If the former, I'd just say _Dean Shrivastava and the twenty members of his faculty took care of the classes_.

Comment: Is 'Dean' a title, or a name?

Comment: @RoaringFish: Dean is title which means _the head of a college or university faculty or department_

Comment: @Ramesh ~ I know that! "Dean" is also a [common personal name](http://www.whosdatedwho.com/sections/celebrities/first-name/Dean), which is what make me ask if Dean was his first name ("Hi! I'm Dean Shrivastava!") or his title.

Comment: @RoaringFish: Yeah, I understand the confusion.

Comment: It is also a surname. One could have Dean Dean Dean.

Answer (score 5):

*Team*.

From my American English viewpoint, *gang* is frightening, and *crew* more subtly negative.

*Work party* sounds weird -- I associate *party* with a group of people waiting at a restaurant, a diplomatic delegation, or a group on an expedition.

Comment: "Work party" is perfectly normal American English. In some contexts, though, it's [working party](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/working-party) or [work detail](http://www.civilization.ca/cwm/games/overtop/glossary_e.shtml): "a specific task assigned to an individual or group, usually entailing physical labour." Common in the military and Boy Scouts.

Comment: "Work party" to me sounds like there's gonna be drinking at work.

Comment: I think the military and Boy Scout people who created the term deliberately used "party" to put that "fun" spin on it.

Answer (score 2):

The clue to focus on is that these people are teachers, and taking classes. If they were labourers, *gang* or *crew* would be fine (*gang* does have some criminal overtones, but not enough to make it unusable); if they were press ganged to clear the road outside the college then *work party* would be normal, but professionals doing their job would prefer to be called a *team*.

Answer (score 1):

Like ash, I would go with team (*A number of persons associated in some joint action*), but for different reasons.

*Gang* suggests drug wars and the like (*"Any band or company of persons who go about together or act in concert (chiefly in a bad or depreciatory sense, or associated with criminal societies)*- OED), and even without them a gang was a bunch of labourers (*A company of workmen* - OED) which doesn't really suit your sentence.

*Crew* suggests a bunch of people running a ship, aircraft, or train or in more modern times a retail outlet of some sort, which again doesn't really fit your sentence.

*W.ork party* is more of an ad hoc thing. OED - "*a group of people who come together to carry out a piece of work of mutual or social benefit*".  Maybe it is just my own experiences, but I tend to associate *work party* with voluntary and/or conservation work.

Answer (score 1):

> Dean Shrivastava and his __ of **twenty faculty members** took care of the classes.

We need to look no further than the existing sentence for the right expression in the given context.

The phrase *twenty faculty members* already exists, and the fact need not be re-stated.

> Dean Shrivastava and **a faculty of twenty members** took care of the classes.

Helpfully also, the referred Shrivastava happens to be the Dean, so that the other members might be "assigned" to him. (Except that *his faculty* could have other implications, the primary meaning of *faculty* being quite another thing.)

> Dean Shrivastava and **his faculty of twenty members** took care of the classes.

Phrasing a sentence appropriately improves readability.